# Default heap for a process

Tags: windows, memory-management, process, heap-memory

I read this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810603) which is about `Managing heap memory` written by Randy Kath.
I would ask about this segment:

> Every process in Windows has one heap called the **default heap**.
>   Processes can also have as many other dynamic heaps as they wish,
>   simply by creating and destroying them on the fly. The system uses the
>   default heap for all global and local memory management functions, and
>   the C run-time library uses the default heap for supporting malloc
>   functions.

I did not underestand what is the function or benefit of the default heap?

Also, I have another question, the author referred always to `reserved and committed space`, what is meant by `committed space`?

Comment: A bit tangentially: I think on of the Channel 9 talks said that the debug version of MSVC10 programs uses a private heap for its dynamic allocations.

Comment: It is an article from 1993.  Archeologically interesting, but whatever it says about the CRT hasn't been true for a long time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Applications need heaps to allocate dynamic memory. Windows automatically creates one heap for each process. This is the default heap. Most apps just use this single default heap.

*Committing* is the act of assigning *reserved* virtual addresses to specific memory so that it is available for use by the process. I suggest you read this article on MSDN: [Managing Virtual Memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810627.aspx).

Comment: Having a default heap simplifies cross-component memory allocation/free, since both sides can just agree to use the default heap. Otherwise, the two sides would have to have some other way of coordinating their allocations.

Comment: @raymond In theory yes but in practice that rarely happens and we have the link to the dynamic runtime dance. May be that precedent was set in the early days when Windows heap allocation performance was not what it is today.